# Is Angular 2 Isomorphic? Will it be in the future?

Tags: javascript, angular, isomorphic-javascript

Been reading up a lot on Isomorphic frameworks and curious as to whether Angular 2 can be considered "Isomorphic". It doesn't seem to be included on any lists, but that may well be because it's still very new.

I have read that Angular 2 is less tightly coupled with the DOM than AngularJS, but it does not however support server rendering. Judging from this link

https://github.com/mbujs/isomorphic-angular

Angular 2 doesn't seem to be classed as Isomorphic by default, however it looks like it is heading that way.

Very general question I know but just looking to see if anyone has any thoughts or opinions on the matter, or whether in fact it actually matters!

Thanks

Comment: server-side rendering is separate project called [Angular Universal](https://github.com/angular/universal)

Answer (score 0):

This document is old. It's planned for Angular2 to support server rendering, it might work already (don't know the current status).
See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1810, https://angularu.com/VideoSession/2015sf/angular-2-server-rendering

Answer (score 0):

It's *looking* to be like the creators of Angular 2 *want* it to be multi-platform (so, yes, server side rendering). If you browse [their source code on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/angular2/platform) you can see that they have a few modules for both server-side and browser-side "platforms" - a platform provides the `bootstrap` method to the library using Angular2, enabling it to start an application (think `angular.bootstrap`).

Unfortunately the `server.ts` is currently empty so it looks like right now, no, it is not isomorphic. It would appear that Angular2 uses an [adapter pattern](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/platform/browser/browser_adapter.ts) for connecting to the native browser API, so it's entirely possible that an adapter just needs to be written for the server side for this to work.

There's no feature tracking other than the issue that Gunter linked above, so that would be your best bet to keep tabs on the feature.

Interestingly there also appear to be source files for web workers.

Don't worry if you get lost navigating the GitHub repo, for some reason the Angular2 repo looks like it has been intentionally hard to navigate with mixtures of dart and ts everywhere